# Connecting Asus ZenScreen MBC16 to Mid-2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: high-sierra, usb, thunderbolt

I bought this nifty Asus ZenScreen to have a second monitor on the go. What could go wrong, right? Well, everything it seems. I am running High Sierra (10.13.6). The ZenScreen takes USB-C input with only one port. The first attempt was to connect via the USB side by downloading the DisplayLink UserAgent 4.3.1 driver. It seems that Apple doesn't want us to do that for some reason? I can connect and it will display a picture- but only a static one. As in, if I have a video playing, only a still image appears, and clicking in that extended desktop will only update to that next snapshot. (A video of this can be provided if need be.)

Next, I tried HDMI to USB-C. And learned that HDMI does not provide power.

Third, I purchased the seemingly overpriced Thunderbolt Cable and USB-C adapter, as the internet informed me that Thunderbolt does in fact provide power. Still no avail.

Now I have a lovely paperweight and several cords that I don't need to boot. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an Asus ZenScreen should be fine. The only issues I've ever seen people have is that the auto sensing orientation feature (to switch between landscape and portrait modes) seems to be somewhat glitchy.

Considering you're on macOS High Sierra, you should be using the [ASUS MB series driver v4.3](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/LCD%20Monitors/MB168B/ASUS_MB_series_driver_for_Mac_OS_10.13_or_before.dmg).

Even if you have already installed this, I would suggest downloading/installing it again. Once you do, go to **Apple > System Preferences... > Security & Privacy**.

*If you're prompted to enter your credentials to unlock the Preference Pane, then enter them in.*

Next, check to see if you have a message at the bottom of the window asking you to allow use of the software (If so, you'll see an <kbd>Allow</kbd> button near the bottom right. Click on this.)

You will most likely be prompted to restart your Mac. Do this and test to see if you can get your ZenScreen to work.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! I felt like it was driver issue and sure enough. Thanks for the solve!